AirDatepicker Highlighting cells
I am trying to highlight date cells which contain data using the AirDatepicker library. I do this by comparing the date of each cell using the onRenderCell function to a list of dates. availableDates.includes(_date) will be true on the 12th of April 2024 but for some reason the css class: highlight-date-cell is applying to the date cell corresponding to the 13th of April 2024
// Get Events as a prop
export let events: Array<any>;

// Create list of each start_date present in events
let availableDates: Array<string> = []
events.forEach(element => {
    availableDates.push(element.start_date.split(' ')[0])
});

// Create calendar and highlight date cell if said date is present in my availableDates array
new AirDatepicker('#input', {
    onRenderCell({date}) {
        const _date = new Date(date).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        const highlight = availableDates.includes(_date)

        return {
            classes: highlight ? 'highlight-date-cell' : undefined,
        }
    },
});

